# How can I access the data elements of "calendarEvents" through the "addEventListener"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, addeventlistener, nuxt.js

I try to modify "v-calendar" element of vuetify framework in nuxtJS and I need to get access to "calendarEvents" data elements through the "addEventListener" method, but i don't know how i can do this there.  Please help to solve this problem.

```
<template>
  <v-sheet height="300" class="pt-3">
    <v-calendar
      type="month"
      now="2019-01-08"
      value="2019-01-08"
      event-color="blue"
      :event-margin-bottom="3"
      :events="events"
    ></v-calendar>
  </v-sheet>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      calendarEvents: [
        {
          name: 'Vacation',
          start: '2019-01-15'
        },
        {
          name: 'Meeting',
          start: '2019-01-07',
        },
        {
          name: '30th Birthday',
          start: '2019-01-03',
        },
        {
          name: 'Conference',
          start: '2019-01-21',
        }
      ],
    }),
    mounted(){
       let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.v-event.v-event-start.v-event-end.blue.white--text > div')
       elements.forEach(item => {
           item.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
               console.log(e)
               this.mouseover(e)})
        })
    },
    directives: {
      maybeDoThis:{ 
        inserted: (el, binding, vnode, oldVnode) => {
        console.log(el)
        console.log(binding)
      }}
    },
    methods: {
        mouseover: (ev) => {
            console.log(ev) // ev.target.value don't work here
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to try to leverage the DOM here, you can use the events that the calendar provides you. You can use the `@mousemove:(day/time/interval)="func"` pattern:

```
@mousemove:day="mouseover"
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me, but if i need to adding @dragstart:event="drag" that's stops working?